# How to combine kafka python consumer and ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer client coded in Python like:

```py
def main():
    producer = KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers=kafka_setting['bootstrap_servers'],
        api_version=(0, 10),
        retries=5)

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        bootstrap_servers=kafka_setting['bootstrap_servers'],
        group_id=kafka_setting['consumer_id'],
        api_version=(0, 10),
        session_timeout_ms=25000,
        max_poll_records=100,
        fetch_max_bytes=1 * 1024 * 1024)

    consumer.subscribe((kafka_setting['fetch_url_topic'], ))

    msg_cnt = 0
    for message in consumer:
        msg_cnt = msg_cnt + 1
        vid_url = message.value.decode("utf-8")
        post_processing_url(vid_url, producer)

def post_processing_url(vid_url, producer):
    ...long time to process...
    ...send the process result to another kafka topic...
```

My case is, fetching message from kafka's topic is really fast, but the `post_processing_url` may cost 10 seconds.

After reading [How To Use ThreadPoolExecutor in Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-threadpoolexecutor-in-python-3), I was wondering if maybe we could use threadpoolexecutor to make `post_processing_url` run in another thread in order to make the kafka consume more faster?

And if we could, how to make it?

---

### Update 1

I'm using threading right now, not sure if it will OOM in long term.

```py
import threading

...
    for message in consumer:
        msg_cnt = msg_cnt + 1
        vid_url = message.value.decode("utf-8")
        t = threading.Thread(target=post_processing_url,
                             args=(vid_url, producer))
        t.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you desire using [Multithreading queues in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). So the basic idea would be as follows:

1. Create a queue (this would be shared across different threads)
2. Keep one single thread to write to the queue (since writing is faster)
3. Create a function to read from queue and do the processing. Call this function f.
4. Spawn multiple threads which run f.

The functions you would mostly need are:

[get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get)

[task done](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.task_done)

[put](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put)

EDIT:

```py
import threading, queue

q = queue.Queue()

def worker():
    while True:
        message = q.get()
        print(f'Working on {item}')
        ''' Do the processing on messages '''
        print(f'Finished {item}')
        q.task_done()

# spawn some threads to run worker
threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()


#function to read from kafka
def f():
    for message in consumer:
        q.put(message)

#Either run the function f directly or allocate some thread to run it
f()
# Alter: threading.Thread(target=f, daemon=True).start()

print('All task requests sent\n', end='')
# block until all tasks are done
q.join()
print('All work completed')
```

Comment: I found it works fast without Queue, I've updated the question.

Comment: One of the problems in this case would be when the time taken to do processing is greater than `N`*time taken to read from queue, where `N` is the maximum number of threads you can spawn at a time. I had tried to do some multithreading benchmarking on an entirely different function and Python had thrown the error `Can't start new thread`.

Comment: Thanks for your replying, in Kafka's python SDK, the program would be hold in the `for message in consumer` loop, I am not sure how to combine this `for` loop with python's threading queue

Comment: Why not keep the `for message in consumer` loop in a separate function `g`, and let one thread run `g`? And then spawn multiple threads for the function which does the processing?

Comment: I've edited the answer with some sample pseudo code.

Comment: Yup, now we could consume the message from Kafka very fast, but processing the message still very slow. It seems that the processing `queue.Queue()`  blocks.